# Java Spring save kml file to webapp/resources

Tags: java, spring

I know that generally you don't want to store dynamic files in the webapp directory as they will be overwritten if the war file is redeployed. However for the functionality I am looking for I need these files to be available from within webapp/resources.

Is it possible to create a file a save it into the resources directory?

```
        Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("/resources/xml/someFile"+randomNum+randomChar+".kml"), "utf-8"));
```

Comment: Ignoring the strong "don't do that", sure - its a directory on the file system like any other (assuming its an exploded war)? Are you facing any issues

Comment: Are there other options for uploading files which would be available through the web app? So If I want to create an xml file someone can download, where would I place this?

Comment: Yes - you can use a network file location (so they are accessilbe through a cluster), use a database, or use a local directory - for a non-cluster environment

Comment: Sorry for being ignorant to the subject. I am more of a PHP developer. When performing this action in PHP I would just store the file on the htdoc where the applications files are stored and it would be assessable through the application. What approach would be similar in  java?

Comment: Do you want the new files written by the java app to be accessible through a URL (like content in htdocs?)

Comment: Yes. They need to be accessible through a URL. The app is running on tomcat

Answer (score 1):

Java webapps can be deployed as a .war file or a directory on Tomcat. In case of a .war file there is no directory to write files to.

I guess you can persist your files to a directory (to which you have permissions) outside the Tomcat deployment dir say /home/user/docs.

Then write a Servlet that can read content from that directory. The file name can be passed as a parameter to your servlet. For example /myapp/GetFile?name=foo.txt

You can find an example of a File reader servlet [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0400__Servlet/ReadFileinaServlet.htm)

Comment: Is this really how its done with java? These files are huge huge files. Reading them in to a BufferedReader would create too much overhead.. Ive done somthing similar to this in a different framework with java where the files were written to the exploded jar. The kml files are for one time use.

Comment: The time/performance is same or similar whether you read it through code or server reads it for you from a deployment dir. The underlying mechanism of reading a file and putting it to output stream is same in both cases.

Comment: If I packaged a static xml file in the resources directory under webapp and accessed it with localhost:8080/resources/xml/file.xml. It wouldnt have that overhead, correct?

Comment: Its not overhead - something (the server in this case) will do the work fo reading xml and putting it to the stream, it will be more efficient but still the underlying mechanism of reading file and writing to stream is similar to the code.